# GridData view filter by date and time

Tags: asp.net, gridview, filter

I've got a GridView and I need do filter witch shows me data between dates and times.

```
     <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ExportDataGrid._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <style type="text/css">
        #Select1
        {
            width: 109px;
        }
        #Select2
        {
            width: 109px;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Welcome to ASP.NET!
    </h2>
    <p>
        To learn more about ASP.NET visit <a href="http://www.asp.net" title="ASP.NET Website">www.asp.net</a>.
    </p>
    <p>
        DataGrid here</p>
    <p>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value=" 06:00:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value=" 06:00:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value=" 06:00:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value=" 06:00:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
        <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar2" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
            EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display.">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BatchId" HeaderText="BatchId" 
                    SortExpression="BatchId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="IncTank" HeaderText="IncTank" 
                    SortExpression="IncTank" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="MoblieTank" HeaderText="MoblieTank" 
                    SortExpression="MoblieTank" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Recipe" HeaderText="Recipe" 
                    SortExpression="Recipe" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TransferStart" HeaderText="TransferStart" 
                    SortExpression="TransferStart" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TransferEnd" HeaderText="TransferEnd" 
                    SortExpression="TransferEnd" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TransferVol" HeaderText="TransferVol" 
                    SortExpression="TransferVol" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Operator" HeaderText="Operator" 
                    SortExpression="Operator" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Vessel" HeaderText="Vessel" 
                    SortExpression="Vessel" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="WorkOrder" HeaderText="WorkOrder" 
                    SortExpression="WorkOrder" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DB_user614ConnectionString1 %>" 
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DB_user614ConnectionString1.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [BatchId], [IncTank], [MoblieTank], [Recipe], [TransferStart], [TransferEnd], [TransferVol], [Operator], [Vessel], [WorkOrder] FROM [MoblieFilling] WHERE [TransferStart] BETWEEN @TransferStart+@TimeStart AND @TransferEnd+@TimeEnd  ">

        <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Calendar1" DefaultValue="9/9/2011 2:30:30 PM" Name="TransferStart"   />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Calendar2" DefaultValue="9/9/2012 2:30:30 PM" Name="TransferEnd"  />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1"  Name="TimeStart" Type=DateTime DefaultValue="00:00:00" />
 <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList2"  Name="TimeEnd" Type=DateTime DefaultValue="00:00:00" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

    </p>
    <p>
        You can also find <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=152368&amp;clcid=0x409"
            title="MSDN ASP.NET Docs">documentation on ASP.NET at MSDN</a>.
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

But this doesn't work. How should I use DropList to select right time? Is a declaration good? or should be different?

Comment: What do you enter in "TransferStart"? What is the result? What is the final sql query sent to db? Also describe your business means.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `AutoPostBack="true" and OnSelectIndexChanged="DropDownList_OnSelectIndexChanged"` to your dropdownlist.

```
void DropDownList_OnSelectIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    var filter =  DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

    //Request your data with citeria
    //Re-bind your GridView
 }
```